# failed to map segment from shared object

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen

I am facing problems to load a so file. the issue is that the file is there and is having for the second share file. 
The first *.so is load succesfully but the second one is giving me this error:

```
Error Loading prog2.so: prog2.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
```

when change the order, the prog2.so is load but prog1.so one is facing the same error.

Please advise what should be the problem, this was not working succesfully before. I am using this piece of code to load it

```
handle = dlopen( filename, RTLD_LAZY );  

if( !handle )
{
    const char * err = dlerror();
if (err)
    throw err;
}
```

the program is failing because handle is returning !handle diff to 1.

Comment: My guess is that both libraries use the same addresses, and neither is relocatable. Thus the first one is loaded fine but the second one fails.